# Setting PATH and HOME environment variables of a shell in C

Tags: c, shell, variables, path, environment

I was wondering if it possible to set the HOME and PATH environment variables of a shell from a C program?

I have both the HOME and PATH values stored in strings, but I can't figure out how to get the shell to see this. I tried to use the putenv function however I couldn't get this to work.

Here is the code I have for trying to set the PATH. I read the PATH value from another file.

```
//Find and store path value
   fseek(fp, 5, SEEK_SET);
   fread(path, 28, 1, fp);
   char *varpath = path;
   ret = putenv(varpath);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add the code that you have tried so far to your question.

Comment: Sure thing, I have just done that :)

Comment: Hey, sorry I should be more clear. My C program creates a shell. So for example, before I run my program I can type echo $PATH and it will show me my path. When I run my C program, I need to have echo $PATH say a certain result.

Comment: Is your program acting as a shell by itself, or does it fork a child process that execs a shell? If it's forking a normal shell process, the environment variables should be inherited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child process can not set environment variables for its parent process.

When you run a C program and call `setenv` or `putenv` from within it, the functions change environment variables for the C program and its children – not for the parent shell from which the C program was run.

So you can use the `source` command or similar inside shell to change the program’s environment or use `fork` and `exec` to run a shell from a C program as its child.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have used fork and exec to have other commands, such as ls. Do you have a rough idea on how I could use this to change the HOME and PATH variables?

Comment: do as you do, use `putenv` then fork+exec and in child process there is HOME and PATH as you set, of course if they not call `putenv` by it self.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in .NET but not C++ so I don't have exact code, but hopefully this points you in the right direction... As you clarified in your last comment, you are trying to set env variables in a child process, not the parent, so that is doable.

Instead of just a regular ShellExecute, create a child process and maintain references to the STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR handles. The child process should launch CMD.EXE. After successful start, simply pass a series of SET {name}={value}{newline} sequences to your STDIN stream.

Once the environment is setup, pass the actual command you want to execute to the STDIN stream.

Here is some info on CreateProcess: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

And the .NET version in case it helps to look at it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One way that a program can be used to set environment variables is to have the program write commands which will be executed by a shell calling the program.  The [`resize`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/resize.html) program is designed to do this for `LINES` and `COLUMNS`:

$ resize -u >foo
. ./foo

where foo contains

```
COLUMNS=80;
LINES=40;
export COLUMNS LINES;
```

I did something similar with `PATH` in a program named [`newpath`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:newpath), e.g.,

```
export PATH=$(newpath)
```